# Is tfs2018 rest api 4.0-preview support wiki put method?

Tags: rest, http, tfs, put, wiki

When using put method to update wiki in postman, I got the following :
Request source does not support put method. 
Microsoft docs only have wiki api instruction after version 4.1 ,so is it true or not 4.0 don't support wiki put feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can find that in docs:

1. [Wikis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) for 4.1 contains wiki methods

[image]

2. [REST API Overview for TFS 2015, 2017, and 2018 (RTW and Update 1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/overview?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) does not contain any wiki methods

[image]

Comment: Using azure devops online and specific api version 4.0 preview.1, I can use put method to update. It's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's your TFS version(2018) which not support Wiki put method.

[image]

As your can see, the minimum supported TFS version is TFS 2018 U2.

We have not deprecated any older API sets, TFS 2018 U2 (for example) essentially has all existing API sets (1.0, 2.x, 3.x, 4.0, 4.1). Azure DevOps has all of these plus 5.0,5.1,6.0-preview  (which is currently in preview).

The minimum supported Wiki API version, to understand which APIs are available on a particular Azure DevOps organization ( or TFS project collection, our client libraries do an HTTP OPTIONS request.

For example, to see the available Wiki REST APIs on the patricklu2020 org using *Curl*:

```
curl -X OPTIONS https://dev.azure.com/patricklu2020/_apis/wiki/wikis -u pat:xxx
```

You will get below response:

```
{
"value":
[{"id":"288d122c-dbd4-451d-aa5f-7dbbba070728",
"area":"wiki",
"resourceName":"wikis",
"routeTemplate":"{project}/_apis/{area}/{resource}/{wikiIdentifier}",
"resourceVersion":2,
"minVersion":"4.0",
"maxVersion":"6.0",
"releasedVersion":"5.1"}],
"count":1
}
```

This provides information tells us **Wiki API was introduced in version 4.0**. That's why you can still use Azure DevOps Service with version 4.0-preview of put method to update even though preview it's deprecated.

For more details about Rest API Version related, you could take a look at below links:

- [REST API Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops)
- [API version in TFS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1567)

Comment: Thanks.I updated tfs to 2018u3 and  can use put method with no problem.